# Why it gets the correct data from localStorage only after refreshing the page in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, auth0, lifecycle

I have been unable to deal with this problem in React for a long time and I am asking for your help. I will be very grateful. You going to be my hero? :))
The problem is that I want to assign roles from RoleConnecton to localStorage and then render the components that are suitable for the role.
However, this happens only after the page is refreshed. I don't know how to fix this without the need to refresh the page.

App.js ->

```
const App = () => {
    const { user, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();
    
      return (
        isAuthenticated && (
        <>
        <RoleConnection />
          <Admin dataProvider={jsonServerProvider('Link to database here')} i18nProvider={i18nProvider}>
    {permissions =>[
      localStorage.getItem("role") ==="medic"
      ?
      <Resource name="employee" list={EmployeeList} edit={EmployeeEdit} create={EmployeeCreate} icon={WorkRounded}/>
      : null,
      <Resource name="hospital" list={HospitalList} edit={HospitalEdit} create={HospitalCreate} icon={LocalHospitalRounded}/>,
      localStorage.getItem("role") === "doctor"
      ? <Resource name="order" list={OrderList} edit={OrderEdit} create={OrderCreate} icon={PersonRounded}/>
      : null,
      localStorage.getItem("role") === "medic"
      ? <Resource name="order" list={OrderList} edit={OrderEditMedic} create={OrderCreateMedic} icon={LocalHospitalRounded}/>
      : null,
      <Resource name="patient" list={PatientList} edit={PatientEdit} create={PatientCreate} icon={PersonRounded}/>,
    ]}
          </Admin>
          <LogoutButton />
          </>
        )
      );
    };
    export default App;
```

RoleConnection ->

```
import React from 'react';
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

const RoleConnection = () => {
  const { user, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();
  const auth_id = 'Auth ID HERE';
  fetch(`Link to Auth0/api/v2/users/${user.sub}/roles`, {
    method: 'get',
    headers: new Headers({
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth_id}`
    })
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      let role = data[0].name;
      localStorage.setItem('role', role);


  });
```

After Editing - Thanks to Someone Special

App.js

```
const App = () => {
const { user, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();
const [ role, setRole ] = useState(null)

   useEffect(() => {
     if(user) auth()
  },[user])

  const auth = () => {
    fetch(`Link to Auth0/api/v2/users/${user?.sub}/roles`, {
        method: 'get',
        headers: new Headers({
           'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth_id}`
        })
     })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log("Data: " + data[0].name)
      setRole(data[0].name)

  });

  
  }
  console.log("Check Role: "+ role);
  return (
    isAuthenticated && (
    <>
    
      <Admin dataProvider={jsonServerProvider('Link to database here')} i18nProvider={i18nProvider}>
{permissions =>[
  console.log("Role "+ role),
  role =="medic"
  ?
  <Resource name="employee" list={EmployeeList} edit={EmployeeEdit} create={EmployeeCreate} icon={WorkRounded}/>
  : null,
  <Resource name="hospital" list={HospitalList} edit={HospitalEdit} create={HospitalCreate} icon={LocalHospitalRounded}/>,
  role === "doctor"
  ? <Resource name="order" list={OrderList} edit={OrderEdit} create={OrderCreate} icon={PersonRounded}/>
  : null,
  role === "medic"
  ? <Resource name="order" list={OrderList} edit={OrderEditMedic} create={OrderCreateMedic} icon={LocalHospitalRounded}/>
  : null,
  <Resource name="patient" list={PatientList} edit={PatientEdit} create={PatientCreate} icon={PersonRounded}/>,
]}
      </Admin>
      <LogoutButton />
      </>
    )
  );
};
export default App;
```

At this point, there is no error, but the relevant sections are not displayed.
From the login console, you can deduce that the null value is entered into the role.
However, when I check the data, there is actually a role that should be assigned.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

[image]
[image]

Comment: That happens because the app renders before role is set in local storage and you haven't set up anything to tell the app to rerender when the role value changes. It's weird to use a function that isn't a component as a component. Maybe have a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect instead.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply. I tried to use useeffect but then i had a problem that i cannot use auth0 hook inside useeffect.  I don't have any more ideas :( Would you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you doing is anti pattern. u should move the entire login into App itself.

App.js

```
const App = () => {
const { user, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();
const [ role, setRole ] = useState(null)

   useEffect(() => {
     if (user) auth()
  },[user])

  const auth = () => {
    fetch(`Link to Auth0/api/v2/users/${user?.sub}/roles`, {
        method: 'get',
        headers: new Headers({
           'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth_id}`
        })
     })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      setRole(data[0].name)

  });

  
  }

  return (
    isAuthenticated && (
    <>
    
      <Admin dataProvider={jsonServerProvider('Link to database here')} i18nProvider={i18nProvider}>
{permissions =>[
  role ==="medic"
  ?
  <Resource name="employee" list={EmployeeList} edit={EmployeeEdit} create={EmployeeCreate} icon={WorkRounded}/>
  : null,
  <Resource name="hospital" list={HospitalList} edit={HospitalEdit} create={HospitalCreate} icon={LocalHospitalRounded}/>,
  role === "doctor"
  ? <Resource name="order" list={OrderList} edit={OrderEdit} create={OrderCreate} icon={PersonRounded}/>
  : null,
  role === "medic"
  ? <Resource name="order" list={OrderList} edit={OrderEditMedic} create={OrderCreateMedic} icon={LocalHospitalRounded}/>
  : null,
  <Resource name="patient" list={PatientList} edit={PatientEdit} create={PatientCreate} icon={PersonRounded}/>,
]}
      </Admin>
      <LogoutButton />
      </>
    )
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: This works perfectly for a particular user, but when I try to use user.sub it unfortunately returns a error that user is undefined.
I edited the post, do you know how to fix it?
Thank you very much for your help.
It means a lot to me :)

Comment: instead of using user.sub, use user?.sub , and add a dependency to the useEffect. edited the answer. This is because user may not be defined on first render while waiting for Auth0 to return the correct values

Comment: I did as you said, but unfortunately there is still a mistake.
Could you please spend some more of your time and help me solve this problem?
I haven't been able to solve this problem for a month :(
You have already helped me a lot :)
I've already edited the question.

Comment: whenever u encounter such a situation, add a if-else statement to check if the variable exist. added if (user) in useEffect

Comment: Again i did as you said but still there is not working.
Now i dont have any error, please check edit post.
I think we are close to finish this (I hope)

Comment: during your first render the role is always null, it will be rendered when the fetch is completed

Answer (score 0):

That's actually a misuse of Components. This `RoleConnection` - does it return anything (any JSX)? If not, it shouldn't be rendered.

You could just place its function (the one that gets a `role` and sets it to `localStorage`) somewhere (as @FelixKling said, `App`'s `useEffect()` is probably the best) and just render conditionally.

Last, but not least, that's why you shouldn't rely on `localStorage` solely. What I'd do is to set this `role` as a React variable also (eg. in state). That way you could write a `useEffect()` with this `role` as a dependency.

Comment: You're right.
I'll remember for the future.
I did as proposed by Someone Special but still i`ve got some problem.
Please check my edit questuon.
Thanks for answer :)

Comment: The `user` cannot be undefined if it properly logs to console, you're missing something...